# PHP - Is there a way to find if the PDF is a fillable PDF or Not

Tags: php, pdf

I know using the following code, we can check if the file is a PDF or Not.Is there a way in PHP to check if the PDF is a `fillable PDF` or a Normal PDF.

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
foreach (glob("path/to/files") as $filename) {
    if(finfo_file($finfo, $filename) === 'application/pdf') {
        echo "'{$filename}' is a PDF" . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "'{$filename}' is not a PDF" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
finfo_close($finfo);
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What errors did you get? If no errors displayed please post your PHP error Log. Thank you

Comment: @MarkTwigg I searched on Google and do not find anything related to my question, that's why I am here to see if it is really possible.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493189/reading-pdf-metadata-in-php, If you aren't using Zend, the answer with PDF Parser should work for you.

Comment: @GentlemanMax thanks for the URL, I already checked PDFparsed demo, the metadata does not return anything related to the fillable pdf, please check http://prntscr.com/c6w9r8

Comment: Maybe https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about?

Comment: @user580950 I am also looking for the exact solution. Can you please tell me the solution for it if you find out?