# Read PDF Title from pdf content in PHP

Tags: pdf

How to get PDF Title from PDF content ? PDF Metadata is not getting PDF title .
I want to get PDF Title and Heading of PDF file in php.

Answer (score 1):

Extracting metadata from PDFs can be tricky, because there are multiple places it can be stored in the file (specifically, both the info dictionary and the XMP stream).

This post suggests some PHP toolsets that may be relevant: [Reading PDF metadata in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493189/reading-pdf-metadata-in-php)